# Java JGit - getting clone progress percentage

Tags: java, git

:)

I currently have a code snippet to clone data from a git repo into a local directory:

```
try (Git result = Git.cloneRepository().setURI(url).setDirectory(localPath).call()) {


        // workaround for https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=474093
        result.getRepository().close();

        }
```

It works perfectly fine, but i want to show the user a swing progress bar (i know how to do this) which shows the percentage of how many "objects are received" already.

How could i possibly do that?

PS: I already took a look at the jgit ProgressMonitor objects, but i cant find any tutorial covering the usage of them.

Answer (score 10):

Adjusting to api's can be a headache, especially if there's hardly any examples documented to use. I would changes your code to the example below:

```
try(
    Git result = Git.cloneRepository()
        .setProgressMonitor(new TextProgressMonitor(new PrintWriter(System.out)))
        .setURI(url)
        .setDirectory(localPath).call()
) {
```

`// workaround for https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=474093
    result.getRepository().close();
  }`

Like any other api, the more often you use it the easier it becomes.  I hope the links below help:

http://download.eclipse.org/jgit/docs/jgit-2.0.0.201206130900-r/apidocs/org/eclipse/jgit/lib/TextProgressMonitor.html

http://download.eclipse.org/jgit/docs/jgit-2.0.0.201206130900-r/apidocs/org/eclipse/jgit/lib/BatchingProgressMonitor.html

http://download.eclipse.org/jgit/docs/jgit-2.0.0.201206130900-r/apidocs/org/eclipse/jgit/lib/ProgressMonitor.html

Good luck.

-dag