# JGit clone repository display progress in runtime

Tags: git, clone, progress, jgit, writer

I know it's simular to this one: [Java JGit - getting clone progress percentage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34616354/java-jgit-getting-clone-progress-percentage)

But it doesn't answer my question, and I don't have enough reputation to comment on this :)

I have the JGit clone command:

```
Git.cloneRepository()
        .setURI(uri)
        .setDirectory(Paths.get(path).toFile())
        .setProgressMonitor(new TextProgressMonitor(writer))
        .call();
```

The metrics are correct.  It's just that it outputs result (Receiving objects stage) when its already finished (in one batch). What I want is to see the progress in runtime (percentage), so that I could display it in my progress bar.

I tried to set up flush in my writer, but it didn't help (maybe I do it wrong). It seems that ProgressMonitor just gives it that way and I can do nothing about it.

`git clone --progress` is a nice example of what I want to achieve.
Please help me out, guys.

Answer (score 1):

You will propably need to implement your own ProgressMonitor, the BatchingProgressMonitor behind TextProgressMonitor delays progress reporting and combines some updates into less output.

The [interface](http://download.eclipse.org/jgit/docs/jgit-2.0.0.201206130900-r/apidocs/org/eclipse/jgit/lib/ProgressMonitor.html) is not complex, e.g. the following prints out updates for each single object/file that is transferred:

```
    .setProgressMonitor(new ProgressMonitor() {
        @Override
        public void start(int totalTasks) {
            System.out.println("Starting work on " + totalTasks + " tasks");
        }

        @Override
        public void beginTask(String title, int totalWork) {
            System.out.println("Start " + title + ": " + totalWork);
        }

        @Override
        public void update(int completed) {
            System.out.print(completed + "-");
        }

        @Override
        public void endTask() {
            System.out.println("Done");
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isCancelled() {
            return false;
        }
    })
```